# Converting cm to pixels to cater different sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Have you encountered websites with images where there is a "ruler" of some sort, in which you see centimeters or inches, but the width and height of an image obviously are pixels. I was wondering how can I use the user's input in Cm/Inches and convert it in pixels accordingly?

For example, in this website: https://www.frameshop.com.au/custom-picture-frames, the user can input width and height in CM and the frame on the left adjusts its width and height accordingly. I wonder what is the conversion/formula for that?

I have yet to try using percentages, EM, and REM for this.

Comment: There's no single formula like that, just like there isn't a single scale for maps.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio

Comment: Did you try using the [`cm` CSS unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#absolute_length_units)?

Comment: You need to define a pixel density like ppi/dpi. For instance. 100px at 300dpi/ppi would translate to 0.333 inch (px/dpi) and  0.85cm (inch*2.54)